# Replacing a number variable in json using groovy

Tags: json, jenkins, grails, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a json which has some numbers that I want to make dynamic and replace the value using groovy. Please let me know if there is a better way as I have already used toInteger to convert but not working.
For ex
{
   jobName:"",
   protocolName:"tcp",
   portNo:""
}
I am able to replace the job-name which is string using replace in groovy but I am not able to replace the port number. The final json should look like below

{
   jobName:"myjob",
   protocolName:"tcp",
   portNo:1112
}

Please let me know if there is a way to do that in groovy

Comment: Can you please post the current code you're using to do the string replacement, along with some of the things you've tried for the integer replacement? (Ideally, you could add a [mcve])

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
String str = '{ "jobName":"", "protocolName":"tcp", "portNo":"" }'
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(str)
json.jobName = 'myJob'
json.portNo = 1112
println new JsonOutput().prettyPrint(new JsonOutput().toJson(json))
```

Comment: This works and I tried it but the jenkins have not whitelisted output or builder methods. Is there a way where whitelisted groovy code can be used to convert

Comment: Not sure that I understand you. You can use all groovy's features in Jenkins.